# Prob. 7, Sec. 26 in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: How is the projection onto the first factor closed if the second factor is compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces such that $Y$ is compact. Then how to show that the projection map $\pi_1 \colon X \times Y \to X$ is a closed map?

My effort:

Let $C$ be a non-empty closed set in $X \times Y$, and let $A \colon= \pi_1 (C)$. We need to show that $X-A$ is open in $X$.

Let $x_0 \in X-A$. Then $x_0 \times Y \subset (X \times Y) -C$. Let $N\colon= (X \times Y ) - C$. Then $N$ is opn in $X \times Y$ and 
$x_0 \times Y \subset N$.

Since $Y$ is compact, there is an open set $W_0$ in $X$ such that $x_0 \in W_0$ and $W_0 \times Y \subset N$, by the tube lemma (i.e. Lemma 26.8 in Munkres).

Now if $x \in W_0$, then since $W_0 \times Y \subset (X \times Y) - C$, we have $(W_0 \times Y) \cap C = \emptyset$ and so $x \times y \not\in C$ for any $y \in Y$; therefore $x = \pi_1(x\times y) \not\in A = \pi_1(C)$, which shows that $W_0 \subset X-A$, and hence it follows that $X-A$ is open and thus $A = \pi_1(C)$ is closed.

Is the above proof correct and clear enough? If correct, can we make it any clearer?

Comment: Oddly the wikipedia page on the tube lemma says the two things are equivalent and the page acts like this is somewhat obvious.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tube_lemma

Comment: @GregoryGrant The equivalence stems from the following characterization of closed maps: A mapping $f : X \to Y$ is closed iff for each $y \in Y$ and each open $U \subseteq X$ with $f^{-1} ( y ) \subseteq U$ there is an open $V \subseteq Y$ with $y \in V$ and $f^{-1} ( V ) \subseteq U$.

Comment: @EinHungerkünstler Thanks, that should be an answer to the OP question then.

Comment: In my opinion your proof is correct and clear.

Comment: It’s fine. It’s a little wordy, but that’s better than saying too little, especially when you’re learning.

Comment: @Gregory: It is fairly obvious, essentially by Saaqib’s argument here.

Comment: @EinHungerkünstler Thanks, that's a nice little factoid.

Comment: @castoroccupatus can you please clearly state and prove what you've stated in your comment here?